# Insert Null with coalescing operator PHP

Tags: php

I want to insert NULL in a table with the null coalescing operator ( > php 7)
I always get and empty string from my POST variables and I did this :

```
$phone = !empty($this->$_POST['phone']) ?? "NULL";
```

But when I dump the result of $phone, it's always false...

Thank you

Comment: "The null coalescing operator returns its first operand if it exists and is not NULL; otherwise it returns its second operand." - the return value of `empty` is always a boolean, so even after you negate it, it is still a boolean - and that very much "exists."

Comment: If you want to use `NULL` as the content, why not use that instead of a string with the content `NULL`?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `$phone = $this->$_POST['phone'] ?? "NULL";`

You are getting `false` because of `empty()` returns boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that there is a difference between "NULL" and NULL in SQL (and almost everywhere else).

I don't think the null coalescing operator does what you want it to do. It only works if you're starting with a null value, not if you want to turn a falsy value into null.

You could do `$phone = !empty($this->$_POST['phone']) ? $this->$_POST['phone'] : null;`, or probably just `$phone = $this->$_POST['phone']) ?: null;`